# Can't access files using npx in a Process in a job in Laravel

Tags: laravel, npm, tailwind-css, npx

Basically, when there is an action X, the app will trigger a job that will trigger this command "npx tailwindcss -i ./private-tw/input.css -o ./public/output.css -c ./private-tw/tailwind.config.js"

And I get this error: "Specified input file ./private-tw/input.css does not exist."

It's an error from "npx", but I think it is caused by the fact that it's inside of a Process.

Of course, this command works outside of the process.

```
        $code = "not relevant here";

        if(!is_dir(base_path('private-tw'))) {
            mkdir('private-tw', 0777, true);
        }

        file_put_contents(base_path('private-tw/designs.html'), $code);

        $tw = Process::run('npx tailwindcss -i ./private-tw/input.css -o ./public/output.css -c ./private-tw/tailwind.config.js');

        if($tw->errorOutput() != '') {
            throw new \Exception($tw->errorOutput());
        }
```

How could this be solved?